# Passing data between variables inside a class in C++

Tags: c++, class

I don't fully understand nor did i find anything online about this topic but this code(cut down so it wont be 500 lines of code):

```
class Character{
public:
int MaxHP;
int currentHP;
currentHP = MaxHP;
int getHP()
{
    return CurrentHP;
}
Character(int h){
    maxHP=h
};
~Character(){};
};
int main()
{
Character warrior(300)
cout<<getHP();
return 0;
};
```

maxHP = 300
CurrentHP = -875000
now trying to acces the value of currentHP i get -87878....
My question is what is the problem?

Comment: This code can't compile.  Please share your [mre] that gives you the bad output

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to initialize a private variable it's better done in a constructor:

```
class Character{
private:
    int MaxHP;
    int currentHP;
public:
    Character() : MaxHP(0), currentHP(MaxHP){}
}
```

Comment: This is a bad technique to use.  It's very brittle.  If someone changes the order of the class member in the class, then this would have UB.

Comment: That's the reason you use the order of declaration in the initializer list.

Comment: The order of the initialization list doesn't matter.  That's why this is a bad technique.  Class members are always initialized in the order they are declared in the class.  If I change the order of the declared members, I don't want to have to remember to check every constructor as well.

Comment: What i'm trying to get are two variables 1 that takes the value of the Hp that i got from the object and the second is changing its value when taking damage. After the fight ends i want to add to the value that is MaxHP lets say +5 and pass it to the variable currentHP so that it can take damage again. So the process is start the fight with 300 hp lose some amount and after the fight is over reset the value back to 300 and add 5 on to it. Start a new fight with 305 Hp and so on.

Comment: your code is not wrong (missing `;` aside), but it is fragile. Suppose the next person working on it likes to sort members alphabetically. They can even have warnings turned on to get informed about wrong oder of the initialization list, but after "fixing" that the code silently compiles and has UB: https://godbolt.org/z/rddG8cj19